# Inline-block elements not appearing as expected

Tags: html, css, alignment, display

I am trying to align two different divs next to each other using inline-block, but they are instead stacking like a blocked element. Specifically, they are the wrapper_image div containing an image, and the about_div containing some text information.

I have the following HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        ... header information here
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper_image">
        <img src="img/1935323_10153090821883239_4407778661294134622_n.jpg"  class="profile-photo">
    </div>
    <div class="about_div">
        <h3 id="about_me">About Me</h3>
        <p id="about_me_info">
            Text
        </p>
        <p id="about_me_info">
            Some more text
        </p>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>
            &copy; Name
        </p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper_image {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.about_div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.profile-photo {
    max-width: 350px;
    border-radius: 100%; /* adds rounded corners to an element */
}

#about_me {
    font-size: 2em;
}

#about_me_info {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

everything seems oks.
I put a demo picture and display in chrome and this is what looks like
[image]

The image and the text are inline-block and seems ok

Comment: so i've figured out the problem: the text in the second div isn't wrapping; instead, it's breaking out of the inline-block and moving everything onto a second line. i just need to find out how to prevent this.

Comment: i've found a solution, though not sure if this is technically correct/widely used. i just put the second div as a child of the first; this way, they are automatically on the same line and the second cannot break.